# C sharp code terminates without exception

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static bool Run(IntPtr handle, IntPtr imethodName, IntPtr iobject, IntPtr itransaction, IntPtr imethod )
    {
      try {
        String methodName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(imethodName);
        CooRuntime.Trace("Executing cooAssembly.GetTypes()");
        Type[] types = cooAssembly.GetTypes();
        CooRuntime.Trace("Executing types[0]");
        Type theType = types[0];
        CooRuntime.Trace("Executing GetMethod >>>>" + methodName + "<<<<");
        MethodInfo method = theType.GetMethod(methodName);
        CooRuntime.Trace("new CooObject");
        CooObject cooobject = new CooObject(iobject);
        CooRuntime.Trace("new CooTransaction");
        CooTransaction  transaction = new CooTransaction(itransaction);
        CooRuntime.Trace("new CooMethod");
        CooMethod coomethod = new CooMethod(imethod);

        CooRuntime.Trace("method.Invoke and return");
        return (bool)method.Invoke( null, new object[] {cooobject, transaction, coomethod} );
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        CooRuntime.Trace("Exception when executing: " + e.ToString());
      }
      catch {
        CooRuntime.Trace("Exception when executing: unknown");
      }
      CooRuntime.Trace("return false");
      return false;
    }
```

The last line in my trace output is "new CooObject". No exception is caught, it looks for mee, that the thread simmply terminates. Since I'm C++ dev not C# I have no idea, where I can search for the reason.

Comment: Try adding a `Finally` and seeing if it gets in there?

Comment: can you post CooObject?

Comment: What is in the constructor for `CooObject`? Could it be a stack overflow perhaps?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but this code is "unsafe", right?

Comment: A coleague of mine told me, that segmentation fault may cause such errors. Yes, it is the constructor of CooObject that causes the problem.